# Position fields in TCA/Backend side-by-side

Tags: typo3, typo3-8.x

In my custom extension, fields in the backend forms (by means of the TCA-configuration) are displayed in vertical order. I would like some of these fields to be positioned side-by-side (horizontally). I can't find any (TCA) options for this. However, the system-based backend-end forms do seem to support this.

I've searched in the official documentation for clues. All I can find is information about how to generate tabs.

How can I position TCA fields side-by-side?

My TYPO3 version is 8.7

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just use palettes.

have a look into the [TCA-manual](https://docs.typo3.org/m/typo3/reference-tca/master/en-us/).
Palettes for [your 8.7 version](https://docs.typo3.org/m/typo3/reference-tca/8.7/en-us/Palettes/Index.html)

Comment: Your answer really helped me into the right direction. Thanks a lot!